# How to fill a specified range of a data table with a matrix

Tags: r, data.table

Below is a minimal example:

```
library(data.table)

#Create example dt
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(ncol = 20, nrow = 2))
colnames(dt) <- c(paste0("COV", seq(10)), paste0("dum", seq(10)))
mapply(function(i) {eval(parse(text = paste0("dt[, COV", i, ":=as.numeric(COV", i, ")]")))},
       seq(10))
sapply(dt, class)

#Create example dt2
dt2 <- matrix(c(seq(10), seq(10)*2), ncol = 10, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
```

`dt2` is 2x10, I want to fill it into `dt[1:2, 1:10]`.

Of course, the for loop solution is straight forward:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
      dt[, paste0("COV", i)] <- dt2[, i]
}
```

But I feel like at the stage of escaping the use of for loop, which seems to be highly discouraged.

I have tried other functions like `sapply`, `mapply`, `do.call`, even combined with `eval(parse(text = sth))`. But so far nothing really works out.

Any suggestion for me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this :

```
 dt[1:2,1:10] <- as.data.frame(dt2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Does it mean that when assigning values to a range in a `dt` or `df` by another `dt` or `df`, but not `matrix`?